# iOS: Simulating user quitting app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just added persistent data into my app and wanted to test it with my iPhone. When I quit my app (double tap home and swipe up), I'm unable to open it again (the icon freezes). When I try the same thing on the iOS simulator in Xcode, it crashes too. I get a SIGTERM error coming from my AppDelegate. Is this what is supposed to happen when the user quits while testing, or is this an issue with my data? Is there any way to simulate the user quitting and restarting the app to make sure my data is still there?

Thanks

Comment: When you try to open the app again, are you still stopped in the debugger? What happens if you continue in the debugger (letting the app terminate) and then try to open the app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct behavior if you are running the app from Xcode. However, once you've uploaded/run the app once, you can test closing and reopening it. Simply stop the run in Xcode, go to your phone or simulator, and click on the app icon to open it. Unfortunately, you won't have a debugger log at that point, but you can see if your data persists.

Comment: Or you can stop the simulator, remove the app from active apps (force quit) and start the simulator again ? (shift + alt + h for home button in simulator)

Answer (score 1):

This is not what is supposed to happen when the user quits while the Xcode debugger is attached (at least not anymore — this question is a couple years old after all).

If you force quit an app while running from Xcode (whether simulator or on a physical device) it just stops the debugger and you should be able to relaunch it without issue. The Xcode debugger will not be attached when you launch like that, but from Xcode you can attach the debugger to an existing process (Debug > Attach to Process).

Note, if run in Xcode and then you *quit* the simulator application on your Mac (or close the simulator's window) then you will get a SIGTERM error in main.swift. But this is not the same as a user terminating your app, nor is it comparable to a user turning off their device.

From what you're describing it sounds like there is a bug in your code that is causing it to freeze when launching when the debugger is detached or when it's relaunching after termination.

To simulate the user quitting and restarting you should be able to terminate the app from your device/simulator, and then either run it again from Xcode or launch it from the device/simulator and attach to the process from Xcode.

In some cases it may be helpful to put in some debugging code that pops up an alert / update some label at runtime to indicate the data persisted properly after the app re-launched so that you don't always have to have Xcode attached to diagnose problems in your app.